# How can I check if my React-Native app is running in a web broswer vs running in an ios/android app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Basically what the title says. I am aware of the Platform component (https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code) which can be used to check what device the app is running on. Although, from my understanding, if the app is running in a web browser on ios/android, Platform wouldn't identify if it's running as an app or in a browser. Can I maybe do something like `document == 'undefined` (true if browser, false if app)? I appreciate any guidance.

I'm using expo by the way.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `window.navigator`?

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I can definitely use this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
  // do something for ios
} else if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  // other thing for android
} else if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
  // it's on web!
} else {
  // you probably won't end up here unless you support another platform!
}
```

I would recommend following the full tutorial provided at the start of the Expo docs, the [Handling platform differences](https://docs.expo.io/tutorial/platform-differences/) section covers this and you may learn other valuable information from the other sections.

Comment: So if the code is being run on an iPad in safari, for example, would Platform.OS return 'ios' or 'web'?

Comment: @NicholasPfeiffer definitely `"web"`; it only returns `"ios"` if the app runs as actual iOS app. The whole point of React *native* is to create native apps. Being able to also run them in a browser using the same codebase is a recent feature.